# Monitor, keyboard, mouse not receiving power, computer takes 4 attempts to power up

Tags: windows-7, usb, display, graphics-card, power-supply

I have a computer with specs listed below. This morning I turned off the computer to install a pair of USB speakers (Logitech Z5). Afterwards, I turned on the computer, it would power up, but then turned off by itself 3 times before finally powered up. But even then, the monitor, the mouse and the keyboard wouldn't receive any power. I suspect the power supply is giving out but I have no way to diagnose the issue. Can you please help me? I'll supply any more information that is requested.

**Relevant specs**:

- OS: Windows 7 x64, regularly and well-maintained
- PSU: Standard TFX 12V, 200W that comes with the InWin BP655 mITX case
- Motherboard: Asus P8H77-I
- Speakers: Logitech Z5 USB speakers
- GPU: Radeon HD 7750 (the monitor is connected via DVI to this card)
- CPU: Intel Core i5 3470 with Intel HD 2500 onboard GPU
- Mouse and keyboard: basic Logitech wireless input devices

**Known facts**:

- When I turn on the computer now, the HDD power indicator light is on and I can hear the (external) hard drives spinning up (the internal disk is an SSD). The internal optical drive also receives power and seems to function normally. **There is no beeping**.
- The speakers were working perfectly with another computer before they got transferred to this one.
- The computer itself was working perfectly before the installation of the speakers.
- During our *first* power up following the installation of the speakers, there was a bootable USB with Ubuntu plugged into the computer.
- **Updated**: the monitor, the mouse, the keyboard and the speakers themselves still work. I just tested by plugging them into another computer.

**Attempts**:

1. I turned off the computer, unplugged the Ubuntu USB, waited a bit, turned it back up. Same issue.
2. I turned off the computer, unplugged the speakers, waited a bit, turned it back up. Same issue.
3. I turned off the computer, switched the DVI cable from the Radeon HD 7750 to the onboard GPU, waited a bit, turned it back up. Same issue.
4. **Updated:** I cleaned up the chassis, blew dust from the fans, made sure the Radeon card was plugged in properly. And the only things plugged into the computer now were: the mouse, the keyboard, a bluetooth USB antenna and the monitor (via DVI to the Radeon). Same issue.
5. **Updated:** I tried booting with a Windows 7 bootable DVD in the optical drive (which receives power). Same issue. The monitor is blank through out.
6. **Updated:** I moved the computer to a different section of the apartment with different outlet. Same issue.

**(Updated 2) Further diagnostics**

7. **RAM testing**: for each of the two RAM sticks, I (i) varied the slot on the motherboard (ii) varied whether the monitor is plugged into the onboard I/O plate or the Radeon DVI out. **Result**: no change; the problem persists.
8. **CMOS resetting**: following the instruction of the Asus board (section 1.9 Jumpers), I cleared the Real Time Clock (RTC) RAM in CMOS. **Result**: no change.
9. **Next step**: I'll either (i) bring the Radeon GPU to a local computer shop to see if it's working, or **(ii) follow any sensible suggestion that you might have**. Thanks!

(**Final update**): the PSU failed and has been replaced. The computer is now working normally!

Comment: Can you clarify what *"unplugged the Ubuntu USB"* in #1 of attempts is referring to? Have you ran any diagnostics? Does it boot and work with a Live CD or other boot CD?

Comment: @CharlieRB When I powered on the system for the first time following the speakers' installation, the Ubuntu bootable USB was plugged in. I thought it could contribute to the issue so in subsequent powering up, the Ubuntu bootable USB was not plugged in. I can try to boot the system with a Windows 7 DVD; will update the main post after I do so.

Comment: @CharlieRB I edited the post.

Comment: Unplug everything and leave it set for an hour, then try again. During that time, verify the monitor is working by connecting it to another PC. If none of that works, run diagnostic tools to check the system (memory, processor, chip-set, video, sound, etc).

Comment: @CharlieRB Thanks! The monitor works for sure because it's being used at this very moment with another computer. I will check the RAM as karel below suggests. But I don't know how to perform any sort of diagnostics for the CPU, chipset, the onboard sound, and the radeon GPU. Can you provide more info / link?

Comment: There are tons of tools available. Depending on the brand, some PC manufacturers offer diagnostic tools on their support sites. Do a search on Super User for *diagnostic tools* and you will find all types of suggestions for various tools by issues.

Comment: It is a good idea to remove everything non-essential to booting (all but one stick ram, the GPU, the non-boot drive etc.) in order to reduce complexity for troubleshooting; the MB may be init'ing the on-chip video; additionally, "double-posting" is not uncommon for motherboards, especially ASUS. Power off is really just a low-power suspend and some MB go through {magic} when power is pulled from the wall (or the plug strip is switched off) and will double-post. I forget why exactly. You might consider a CMOS reset (jumper or pull battery; check manual) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is the failure of the PSU.

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause of the computer taking 4 attempts to power up is a failed  RAM stick. The computer cannot properly identify the broken RAM stick, so it initiates a reboot and after three times it gives up and reboots the computer without using the broken RAM stick. If your computer has more than one RAM stick, try removing the RAM sticks one at a time to find out if your computer will boot normally when one of the RAM sticks is removed.

Sometimes if the RAM stick is not completely broken, the monitor will continue to work and you will get to see if there are any error messages shown during bootup saying that there is a problem with the RAM. Sometimes if the RAM stick is completely broken, you will not get any output on the monitor, only a black screen.

Comment: +1. I appreciate the suggestion. Will test the RAM sticks 1 by 1 and update. The computer has 2 sticks.